# jQuery Validate - How can I validate if a number input is higher than another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this inputs in my form:

```
<h4>Precio de compra:</h4>
Gs. <input required class="corto2" type="number" placeholder="Precio de compra" id="pcompra" name="pcompra" value="{{request.form.pcompra}}">
<h4>Precio de venta:</h4>
Gs. <input required class="corto2" type="number" placeholder="Precio de venta" id="pventa" name="pventa" value="{{request.form.pventa}}">
```

And this rules on my jquery validation script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            pcompra: {
                required: true,
            },
            pventa: {
                required: true,
            },
        }
   }
}
```

What I am looking for, is not validate **pventa** against a hard-coded value, like *min: 20*, what I want is to check if **pventa** value is higher than the value of **pcompra**.

Can I achieve this with a rule method of jvalidate? Or I'll have to add my own rule/function?

*PS:* It's part of a flask web app, so ignore the parts with jinja2 syntax ({{"something"}})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery.validator.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("comparison", function (value, element) {
        var pcompra = $("#pcompra").val();
        return this.optional(element) || value > pcompra;
    });
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            pcompra: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            pventa: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                comparison: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            pcompra: {
                required: 'This field is required.',
                number: 'Please enter a valid number.'
            },
            pventa: {
                required: 'This field is required.',
                number: 'Please enter a valid number.',
                comparison: 'This field should larger than field pcompra'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for some values but is the right solution.. I just have to adjust some things to make it perfect. Thanks!